# Form Stop Submitting After Adding jquery.validate

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, html-helper

here is my Controller Codes:

```
[HttpPost]

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Description,FolioId,Permission,CreatedOn,  CreatedUser,Published")] Categories categories)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
        Guid guid = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
        Methods method = new Methods();

        string NowTime = method.TodayDate(1) + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");

        categories.CreatedUser = guid;
        categories.CreatedOn = NowTime;

        db.Categories.Add(categories);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(categories);
}
```

This is my View :

```
@model XS.Models.Articles.Categories.Categories
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create List";
    Layout = "~/Areas/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

<div style="margin-top:30px;padding-bottom:2px;">
     <img src="~/Content/images/category.png" style="position:absolute;" />
     <h3 style="padding-top:20px; margin-right:70px;">Lists</h3>
</div>

<hr />

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FolioId)
            <div>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FolioId, Model.FolioName, new { @class = "DropDown_Width150" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FolioName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)

            </div>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Permission)
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Permission)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Permission)
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />

        <div>        
            <label class="switch switch-fullgreen">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Published)
                <span class="switch-label" data-on="Enable" data-off="Disable"></span>
                <span class="switch-handle"></span>

            </label>  

            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Published)
        </div>

        <br />

        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Create List" class="btn btn-success" />
                @Html.ActionLink("Return", "Index")

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
}



<script>     
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Published').addClass("switch-input")
    });
</script>
```

there is no problem in normal . but the problem appear when i add the jquery.validation js files to my project to have a unobtrusive validation .
it happen after i add :

jquery.validate.min.js
and
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

to my Layout .

its the boundle :

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(

                   "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",

                   "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

and in webconfig :

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />

<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have validation messages that you have setup via data attributes in your model. May be from is not getting posted because the clientside validation is asking user to correct the errors.

Comment: Not sure how the bundle things works yet, but make sure the validation scripts load AFTER the main jquery script file.

Comment: Can you check with the browser debugger if any of the input fields have triggered the validation (even if they are hidden). This behaviour can be caused by not nullable types like int or datetime

Answer (score 2):

try changing the order of the files and make sure jquery is referenced also.

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",

                   "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"

));
```